# "LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory" error after installing redis on magento2.4.3

Tags: magento2, cache, magento2.4.3, redis, cm-redissession

Redis is giving this error sometimes "LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory"  and the website is not working, Does anybody have any solution for this